# Waiting for an element without throwing an exception if timed out

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I know of the method `Element#wait_until_present(t)`, but if this method times out it throws a timeOut exception.

Is there a method that just waits for `t` seconds and then returns true if the element became present or false otherwise?

I know it can be done with a simple `begin..rescue..end` statement, but I'm looking for something that doesn't use exceptions.

Comment: There is not. It's certaintly unfortunate that this method raises an exception for such non-excepctional thing, but just write your own extension and be done with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a short-hand `rescue` clause like this:

```
element_present = browser.element.wait_until_present rescue false
puts "element not present" unless element_present
```

This does however result in a `false` value on any `Exception` at all and not just with `TimeoutError`. I still prefer to use it since if there's any `Exception` at all then it would be safer to assume that the element was not present.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is no other method that will do what i'm looking for ,

so here is the simplest method to achieve this :

```
#check method for Element#wait_until_present(t) 
def check_if_present(element,t)
    raise ArgumentError, 't must be a number ' unless t.is_a? Numeric
    begin
        element.wait_until_present(t)
        true
    rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError
        false
    rescue
        raise "Something wrong with the element"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want an exception the below code can be handy:

sleep 'your time here' eg: sleep 20 - this will wait for 20 secs.

then check for your element now:

'your element'.exists? -this will return true/false

you will not get an exception this way.

Another best way is to write your wait_for_load method based on your needs.

Comment: The `sleep t` option will force me to sleep for `t` seconds no matter what . I preferred to write my own method , as i did in the answer i posted just a few seconds after you :)